# How to format strings in Zig using a runtime format string

Tags: string-formatting, zig

I'm a total noob to learning Zig so my question may be naïve.

I'm trying to create a variety of strings in my code using the string formatting functions in the standard library such as [`std.fmt.allocPrint()`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#std;fmt.allocPrint)

It was working when I was just doing one string at a time but when I decided to abstract it into a function the compiler is telling me that `allocPrint`'s format string is [`comptime`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#comptime).

I can't find any way to achieve the same thing using a runtime format string.

Is there a totally different way that involves not using `std.fmt` or am I missing something basic due to being a beginner?

Comment: no. not yet....

Comment: @AliChraghi: Thanks. If you know this for 100% sure you should make it an answer and I'll accept it. Is there a feature request I can follow, or some workaround people use?

Comment: Is it possible for you to change your function to accept a comptime format string too? eg `fn myFn(format: []const u8)` → `fn myFn(comptime format: []const u8)`. If not, could you give a code example of what you're trying to do and why it has to be runtime?

Comment: @pfg: I thought of that last night and haven't tried it yet. I had tried a function that took in a runtime string and converted it to a comptime string, as a kind of hacky shim, and got unexpected results I'l like to ask about on a forum. I think I found a bug or missing error/warning. I don't have to do it the current way but I have a habit of finding such edge cases quickly with every new language. I am checking existence of a set of files whose names are based on the same parameters and if any of certain sets of the files exist the code can proceed.

Comment: @hippietrail It shouldn't be possible to convert a runtime string to a comptime string, as the value of a runtime string can't be known at comptime. If the code compiled, that is likely a bug. The discord is probably a good place to ask about something like that: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Community

Comment: My idea was to have the set strings exist at comptime and then match the runtime one against the comptime one and then pass the comptime one. But I can't even iterate through a const array of format strings. It seems harder to reason about than I was expecting.

Comment: @hippietrail To iterate over comptime strings, you need to use a comptime loop: `inline for(.{"string one {s}", "string two {s}"}) |format_str| { std.log.info(format_str, .{"arg"}); }` https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#inline-for . You can't make a function that returns a comptime string from a runtime string though, because the result of that function needs to be known at comptime but depends on a runtime value

Comment: @pfg Thanks. So you can't inline such a function like you can inline a loop? I thought either way it would end up unrolling/instantiating since the format strings are always part of a fixed set known at compile time.

Comment: @hippietrail You can inline a function by doing `comptime fncall()`, or it will inline automatically if all its arguments are marked as `comptime` (sometimes you have to wrap the body of the function in `comptime { … }`, I think there's an open zig bug for this)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to achieve with function `allocPrint`. A small code example would be helpful to understand your question and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Zig's printing functions expect format strings that are known at compile time. You can use C's printf if you need a dynamic format string.

Here's something I got running on version 0.12.0-dev.2296+46d592e48.

```
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("stdio.h");
});

const std = @import("std");

// Returns a null-terminated heap-allocated string, usable in C, containing the phrase "hi " repeated numHis type.
const hi = "hi ";
fn getHis(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, numHis: usize) ![*:0]u8 {
    const total_len = numHis * hi.len;
    // allocSentinel ensures it ends with a \0.
    const s = try allocator.allocSentinel(u8, total_len, 0);
    var i: usize = 0;
    while (i < total_len) : (i += hi.len) {
        // repeatedly copy the phrase into the allocated memory.
        std.mem.copyForwards(u8, s[i .. i + hi.len], hi);
    }
    return s;
}

// Returns a null-terminated heap-allocated string, usable in C, containing some border chars and the phrase "%s", which can be passed as a format string to c's printf.
const strInsert = "\n%s\n";
fn getBorderedFormatString(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, borderChar: u8) ![*:0]u8 {
    const total_len: usize = 20 + strInsert.len + 2; // add 2 for leading and trailing newline
    const s = try allocator.allocSentinel(u8, total_len, 0);
    var i: usize = 0;
    s[i] = '\n';
    i += 1;
    while (i < 11) : (i += 1) {
        s[i] = borderChar;
    }
    std.mem.copyForwards(u8, s[i .. i + strInsert.len], strInsert);
    i += strInsert.len;
    while (i < total_len - 1) : (i += 1) {
        s[i] = borderChar;
    }
    s[i] = '\n';
    return s;
}

test "dynamic_phrase" {
    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();
    const allocator = arena.allocator();
    const s = try getHis(allocator, 30);
    const f = try getBorderedFormatString(allocator, '+');
    _ = c.printf(f, s);
}
```

I'm new at Zig, so maybe there is a way to use dynamic format strings in Zig directly. If so, I didn't easily discover it.

Comment: It never occurred to me to use the C interop! I ended up writing my own partial implementation of `allocPrint` without runtime format strings and I kept trying to get something working where the format strings were `comptime` but the logic of selecting which one was runtime. I can't remember if I got that working in the end as it was just a learning exercise and I moved on.

Comment: I did this as a learning exercise too. I think I probably don't actually need dynamic format strings, but I got a bee in my bonnet about not being able to obviously do it.